# Adding plain text destroys nice shapes and shadows on tittle page - beamer Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, titles

I am creating a presentation for defending my thesis and I needed to add the name of my supervisor to title page. I did it using code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271222/how-can-i-add-plain-text-to-a-titlepage-in-beamer) ... It works fine when I consider adding the plain text, but it destroys nice shape of the color frame and its shading which is under the title as default on title page of this theme. I know that by redefining the title page I somehow "turned off" these features but I would like to turn them on again since it looks good.

Here is my code (not sure whether it will work here):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Aplikácia metódy združených asymptotických rozvojov vo finančnej matematike.}
\subtitle{Application of matched asymptotic expansions method in financial mathematics.} 
\author%[Author, Anders] % (optional, for multiple authors)
{Bc. Jozef Janočko}
\institute[Universities Here and There] % (optional)
{

  Fakulta matematiky, fyziky a informatiky\\
  Univerzita Komenského
 }

%{RNDr. Be\'{a}ta Stehl\'{i}kov\'{a}, PhD.}
%\subject{Computer Science}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \flushleft RNDr. Beáta Stehlíková, PhD.
    \vskip0.5em%
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate \\
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
} 
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}


\end{document}
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: Text is added]

This is how it looked before:

[image: Without added text]

Comment: Can you post an image of the output title page to illustrate the problem?  It's quite hard to follow where the issue is, but looking at the question you link to that seems to heavily redefine the title page so there may be a simpler change which has the same effect without interefering with the theme.  It would also be helpful if you could provide code for a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/)

Comment: Could you please add a MWE, that includes the theme you are using? As the titlepage definitions vary from theme to theme, you have to modify the right one.

Comment: OK, I'll change my first post to include these.

Comment: If there was a simper ways how to add only that one line of text I would definitely choose that one but I haven't find that option anywhere till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title[short version for footline]{Aplikácia metódy združených asymptotických rozvojov vo finančnej matematike.}
\subtitle{Application of matched asymptotic expansions method in financial mathematics.} 
\author%[Author, Anders] % (optional, for multiple authors)
{Bc. Jozef Janočko}
\institute[Universities Here and There] % (optional)
{

  Fakulta matematiky, fyziky a informatiky\\
  Univerzita Komenského
 }

%{RNDr. Be\'{a}ta Stehl\'{i}kov\'{a}, PhD.}
%\subject{Computer Science}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \flushleft RNDr. Beáta Stehlíková, PhD.   % NEW
    \vskip0.5em                                                             % NEW
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The shading still does not work for me for some unknown reason but at least the shape is nice again. Thx very much :)

Comment: Did you try with the exact same code from my answer? How are you compiling? I used pdflatex from texlive2016

Comment: I copied just the body of \setbeamertemplate macro ... and I use pdflatex through TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Did you also copy the `\makeatletter` things? Otherwise can you update your MWE?

Comment: No, since I want to have a beamer and not a letter. But I think this aswer is fine. I did not achieve everything but I have next 15-20 slides to do and a cannot spend days with the first one.

Comment: Aaahhh OK, I understand... now I copied \makealetter and \makeatother a it works fine.... thx very much! :)
Could you also explain why that is needed? (since it was not in original code in the link I provide in my question)

Comment: @JozefJanočko The `\makeatletter` is needed, because I use `shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow` to ask if the theme you are using has a shadow or not. And as there are @ signs in this expression one has to convert this in a normal letter (in the sense of a character not the paper you write to your aunt :) to use it.